# 12.04 Login gone wrong

Tags: 12.04, login, login-screen, users

I seem to have a fault in the login procedure somewhere.  When I boooted up I found that if I selected Guest I could use the computer.  If I selected my administrator account I was taken straight to the terminal. So I opened a guest session, went to user settings, and unlocked my admin account (it accepted the password!), and amended it to show "password None" and automatic login.  I now find that when I boot up I am taken straight to the terminal - if I exit terminal I get the login screen - if I select the administrator login I go back to terminal - if i select guest I can use the PC, and if I select mu normal user account I can use the PC.  So I cannot login as an administrator - so admin functions such as update are no longer accessible.
Sorry to be so long winde but I am stuck.

Can anyone suggest anything - I am a beginner with this

Comment: Please make sure that your session type is "Ubuntu" before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is to create a new admin user from terminal. Then, once you are sure that the new account works properly, delete the old admin account.

Here's how:

```
adduser <username> admin
```